# How to rename json object name with java annotation?

Tags: java, json, spring

How to rename json object name with java annotation?
Object structure in java:

```
public class ParentClass {
   private MyClass myClass;
}

public class MyClass {
   private String name;
}
```

Json will have next view:

```
{
   "myClass":{
      "name":"value"
   }
}
```

How can I change name of "myClass" using java/spring annotations, something like

```
 @JsonObjectName("abc")
 public class MyClass {
       private String name;
    }
```

and json will look like:

```
{
   "abc":{
      "name":"value"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the variable:

```
private MyClass myClass;
```

To:

```
private MyClass abc;
```

This will yield the correct JSON-output without the use of annotations.

If you still want to use annotations and keep the name of the variable you can use `@JsonProperty()`:

```
@JsonProperty("abc") // name of the property
private MyClass myClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

@SerializedName("abc") is also possoble

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework you are using. If you are using Jackson Library you can use:

```
public class ParentClass {
   private MyClass myClass;
}

@JsonProperty("abc")
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
}
```

If you are using Gson then

```
 @SerializedName(value = "abc")
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
}
```

Additionally in Gson if you want to use any alternate name for the field during deserialization we can use `alternate` as below:

```
 @SerializedName(value = "abc", alternate ="xyz")
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
}
```

**alternate** is to be used only at time of **deserialization** and **GSON** will only process/deserialize the last occurence of that field from JSON data.